# Mobile Apps Java and HTML

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know a framework to develop a mobile application for Android with Java and HTML?

I mean develop UI with HTML (to reuse it with an other OS) and native functions with Java.

For the moment I am trying to develop multiplatform apps with Qt but it's quite complex to use native functions from Java, that's why I'm looking for an easier way to do it.

Comment: you can  go for Phonegap or ionic Framework

Comment: React Native, PhoneGap

Comment: the **UI** is literally the only thing in the application that is completely not worth "unifying" using HTML. Application logic maybe, but the UI? eh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can find this kind of framework.

If you meet some problems to use native functions with Qt I recommend you to watch BogDan Vatra videos and pdf

https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/BogdanVatra_Extending_Qt_Android_Apps_with_JNI.pdf

Besides, you should look at the QtAndroidNamespace class and runOnAndroidThread function.

Edit : You can find the videos in the Tutorials part of QtCreator

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the Java but using **javascript**,we have alot of Frameworks like Titanium, Sencha Touch and  PhoneGap etc.In this you can simply use the html,js,and css3 bundle to creates the IOS Android and as well as web.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against reusing the UI on different mobile operating systems - it will always look as if it doesn't belong on one of those systems. Creating an Android UI isn't that complicated, you should try it.

That said, you could have just one big WebView on your native UI, displaying your HTML UI. You might need a web server in your app, serving the UI, though - I'm not sure.